# vue.js and laravel simple form submission with vuetify

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

Hello everyone I just used vuetify yesterday and it seems like I'm having an error with a axios.post form submission. I'm confused on what seems to be the error on this code. It is mostly the same with my previous project except with vuetify this time.

Here is my code.

**Template** My component.vue template field.

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="search"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="departments"
      :search="search"
      :items-per-page="5"
    >
    <template v-slot:top>
      <v-toolbar flat color="white">
        <v-toolbar-title>Department</v-toolbar-title>
        <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        <v-dialog v-model="dialog" max-width="500px" persistent>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
            <v-btn color="primary" dark class="mb-2" v-on="on">Add Department</v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card>
            <v-card-title>
              <span class="headline">{{ formTitle }}</span>
            </v-card-title>

            <v-form @submit.prevent="save()">
            <v-card-text>
              <v-container>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col cols="12" sm="12" md="12">
                    <v-text-field v-model="department" label="Department Name"></v-text-field>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-container>
            </v-card-text>

            <v-card-actions>
              <v-spacer></v-spacer>
              <v-btn color="blue darken-1" text @click="close()">Cancel</v-btn>
              <v-btn type="submit" color="blue darken-1" text>Save</v-btn>
            </v-card-actions>
            </v-form>
          </v-card>
        </v-dialog>
      </v-toolbar>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:item.action="{ item }">
      <v-icon small class="mr-2" @click="editItem(item)">edit</v-icon>
      <v-icon small @click="deleteItem(item.id)">delete</v-icon>
    </template>
    <template v-slot:no-data>
      <v-btn color="primary" @click="initialize()">Reset</v-btn>
    </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

**Script** My component.vue script field.

```
   <script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      search: '',
      departments: [],
      department: '',
      dialog: false,
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Department Name',
          align: 'left',
          sortable: true,
          value: 'department_name',
        },
        { text: 'Created By', value: 'department.created_at' },
        { text: 'Created At', value: 'department.created_at' },
        { text: 'Actions', value: 'action', sortable: false },
      ],
      editedIndex: -1,
      editedItem: {
        name: '',
      },
      defaultItem: {
        name: '',
      },
    }),

    computed: {
      formTitle() {
        return this.editedIndex === -1 ? 'New Item' : 'Edit Item'
      },
    },

    watch: {
      dialog(val) {
        val || this.close()
      },
    },

    created() {
      this.initialize()
    },

    methods: {
      initialize() {
        axios
        .get('/api/departments')
        .then(response => this.departments = response.data)
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
      },
      editItem (item) {
        this.dialog = true
        this.editedIndex = this.departments.indexOf(item)
        this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, item)
      },
      deleteItem(id) {
        if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?') && this.departments.splice(index, 1)) {
          axios
          .delete(`/api/department/${id}`)
          .then(response => this.initialize())
          .catch(error => console.log(error))   
        }
      },
      close() {
        this.dialog = false
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.editedItem = Object.assign({}, this.defaultItem)
          this.editedIndex = -1
        }, 300)
      },
      save() {
          axios
          .post('/api/department', {
                      department: department,
          })
          .then(response => this.initialize())
          .catch(error => console.log(error))

        this.close()
      },
    },
  }
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
 public function store(Request $request) {

    $request->validate ([
      'department' => 'required',
    ]);

    $department = Department::updateOrCreate([
      'department_name' => $request->department
    ]);

    return response()->json([
      'message' => 'Add Success'
    ], 200);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in `save` method you need to change `department` to `this.department` that is inside your block scope

```js
save() {
    axios.post('/api/department', {
         department: this.department,
    })
}
```

**Update**

Based on @Ohgodwhy suggestion:

```js
save() {
    const { department } = this

    axios.post('/api/department', { department })
}
```

Comment: @JimERussel happens :)

Comment: You could also clean it up a little bit with some destructuring: `const { department } = this`, then `{ department }` is your argument.

Comment: Could you please provide an example based on my code?

Comment: @JimERussel updated my answer with Ohgodwhy suggestion

Comment: Thank you guys! Can I ask a bonus question? How do I use the @store controller for both post and put method usiong axios in laravel? I still haven't done the edit method for this and I don't know how. Sorry.